# ¿Cómo cargar una foto en un formulario con PHP Javascript y Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un formulario con el que inserto empleados:

```
const nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
const apellidos = document.querySelector('#apellidos').value;
const foto = document.querySelector('#foto').value;
const accion = document.querySelector('#accion').value;

const infoContacto = new FormData();
            infoContacto.append('nombre', nombre);
            infoContacto.append('apellidos', apellidos);
            infoContacto.append('foto', foto);
            infoContacto.append('accion', accion);
            insertarEmpleadoBD(infoContacto);
```

Mediante la siguiente función envío los datos al controlador:

```
    function insertarEmpleadoBD(datos){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //Abrir la conexión
        xhr.open('POST', '../controller/empleadoControlador.php', true);
        xhr.onload = function()
        {
            if(this.status === 200)
            {
            console.log("el empleado se ha insertado con éxito");
            }
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("../index.php"); 
            }, 2000);
        }
        xhr.send(datos)
    }
```

Y aquí, el controlador hace el insert:

```
     //esta es la línea 15:
     if ($_POST['accion'] == 'crearEmpleado'){

     $dir='../img/';
     $nombreArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['name'];

     if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$dir.$nombreArchivo)){
      echo "error en la subida de la foto<br>";
      echo "<a href='../views/empleadoAltaFormulario.php'>Volver</a>";
      exit;
      }

    $empleado = new Empleado();

    $idEmpleado = $empleado->setIdEmpleado($_POST['idEmpleado']);
    $password = $empleado->setPassword($_POST['password']);
    $nombre = $empleado->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
    $apellidos = $empleado->setApellidos($_POST['apellidos']);
    $email = $empleado->setEmail($_POST['email']);
    $departamento = $empleado->setDepartamento($_POST['departamento']);
    $costeHora = $empleado->setCosteHora($_POST['costeHora']);
    $foto = $empleado->setFoto($nombreArchivo);

    $empDao = new EmpleadoDAO();

    $empDao->insertarEmpleado($empleado);
}
```

El caso es que si comento (/**/) o elimino todo el código relacionado con la foto, el registro se inserta sin foto. Pero si la tengo en cuenta, me sale el mensaje en la consola de que se ha insertado correctamente. No salta ningún error ni en php ni en js, pero en la BBDD el registro no aparece, o sea, que en realidad no se inserta.

¿Alguien sabe lo que puede estar mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes reemplazar:

```
const foto = document.querySelector('#foto').value;
```

Por:

```
const foto = document.querySelector('#foto').files[0];
```

Así:

```
const nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
const apellidos = document.querySelector('#apellidos').value;
const foto = document.querySelector('#foto').files[0];
const accion = document.querySelector('#accion').value;

const infoContacto = new FormData();
            infoContacto.append('nombre', nombre);
            infoContacto.append('apellidos', apellidos);
            infoContacto.append('foto', foto);
            infoContacto.append('accion', accion);
            insertarEmpleadoBD(infoContacto);
```

Y por último, revisar los privilegios del directorio destino, en este caso, `../img/`.

Referencias:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: Recuerda que responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, edita y explica tu script por favor

Comment: Primero, borra la caché de tu navegador, prueba de nuevo. Si el problema continua, tal vez se debe a que el archivo que intentas subir supera el limite establecido en `php.ini` en la directiva `upload_max_filesize`, no se me ocurre que otra cosa puede ser...

Comment: no... Ese no es el problema. Lo de la caché lo compruebo siempre y el php.ini está revisado porque ya tuve ese problema cuando hacía la carga del formulario por php. El problema está en la función. He probado lo que dice aquí https://cazaresluis.com/ajax-y-php/ pero creo que está incompleto...

Comment: Es este, revisalo, el nombre del archivo es `test.php` https://jsfiddle.net/9u5dg0L8/2/

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94487/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-perez-como-cargar-una-foto-en-un-formulario-con).

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

mucho mas rapido y efectivo

```
<form id="Myform"> all code </form>

const infoContacto = new FormData(document.getElementById("Myform"));
```

esto serializa todo y lo agrega al `formData`